# Subquery using UNION ALL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery, union, union-all

I guess I don't understand the order in which subqueries work.

When I run this SQL statement I get 1 (out of 3 that exist in the table) random 'friend id' :

```sql
SELECT t1.sender_id AS Connections FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT sender_id
                FROM connection
                WHERE receiver_id = 'my_id'
                AND status = 'Approved') t1
                UNION ALL                 
SELECT t2.receiver_id FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT receiver_id
                FROM connection
                WHERE sender_id = 'my_id'
                AND status = 'Approved') t2
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

One random `id` is returned which is what I want.

**BUT**  when I wrap the previous SQL statement within another SQL statement to get the friend's `name` and `id` (from the `id` in sub-query) the results come back randomly as either empty or 1 friend or 2 friends or all 3 friends :

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM profile
WHERE id = (
    SELECT t1.sender_id AS Connections FROM
    
                (SELECT DISTINCT sender_id
                FROM connection
                WHERE receiver_id = 'my_id'
                AND status = 'Approved') t1
                UNION ALL                 
    SELECT t2.receiver_id FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT receiver_id
                FROM connection
                WHERE sender_id = 'my_id'
                AND status = 'Approved') t2
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

I want it to emit the same behaviour as the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the subquery is being re-executed for every row being tested in `profile`. Each time it returns a different random ID; if that ID happens to match the current row of `profile`, the row is returned.

Instead of using `WHERE id =`, use a `JOIN`. This will just run the subquery once.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM profile AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT t1.sender_id AS Connections FROM
    
                (SELECT DISTINCT sender_id
                FROM connection
                WHERE receiver_id = 'my_id'
                AND status = 'Approved') t1
                UNION ALL                 
    SELECT t2.receiver_id FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT receiver_id
                FROM connection
                WHERE sender_id = 'my_id'
                AND status = 'Approved') t2
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS r
ON p.id = r.Connections
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really asking for all the sender_ids and one receiver_id?

It feels like you have an extra layer of `SELECTs`.

When in doubt, add extra parentheses:

```
( SELECT ... ) 
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ...)   -- this ORDER BY applies only to the select
ORDER BY ...    -- This applies to the result of the UNION, not the second select
```